# How can I extract specific values from all items in axios response object to a a vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex

This is driving me nuts!

I have got an axios call returning an json array object in console - Check!

```
>(100) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>0:
id: 54892250
iid: 1001
ref: "master"
sha: "63e3fc014e207dd4e708749cee3e89a1aa416b7d"
created_at: "2020-03-05T18:57:02.793Z"
updated_at: "2020-03-05T19:06:27.651Z"
>user: {id: someuserid, name: "someuser", username: "someusername", state: "active", avatar_url: "https://assets.gitlab-static.net/uploads/-/system/user/avatar/4534925/avatar.png", …}
>environment: {id: 123456, name: "somename", slug: "somename-iw5iqp", external_url: "https://someaddress.com"}
>deployable: {id: someid, status: "success", stage: "deploy", name: "deploy-staging", ref: "master", …}
status: "success"
__proto__: Object
>1: {id: 54804365, iid: 1000, ref: "filter-out-expired-items", sha: "6225d8018c86fa906063aeea5c10c710ddced14c", created_at: "2020-03-05T12:25:18.949Z", …}
>2: {id: 54804175, iid: 999, ref: "master", sha: "aa5e50c50ba95e9b16cbc57fb968bf9075c625b2", created_at: "2020-03-05T12:24:02.284Z", …}
>3: {id: 54801934, iid: 998, ref: "filter-out-expired-items", sha: "4fc2
```

Now I need to do 2 things with this result:

1. when fully expanded this response is large - and there are thousands of them. Rather than store 1000s of giant json reponses in a vuex state - I want to first only extract the values we care about which are the following:

   - id
   - ref
   - environment.name
   - status
   - deployable.tag

to something like:

```
{ "id": id, "ref": ref, "environment": environment.name, "status": status, "tag": deployable.tag, }
```

How do I do this?

2. This response is paginated over many pages above is just a partial sample from one page's results.

I have a working loop for that and I am getting the console.log for all of them. BUT what I need to do is concatenate all pages (now stripped to the above fields) before I commit to the state. If have tried object copies, pushing to arrays and all kinds of utils promising the world - but I cannot get any of them working :)

So in summary:

1. get a page's results
2. squash item in the array to a simplified version
3. collect them all into a object I can insert into the state

Relevant part of the loop

```
  // Use headers to get the number of pages
  const pages = await axios.head(url, options)
    .then((response) => response.headers['x-total-pages']);
  console.log('pages=', pages); // DEBUG
  // Loop through and push them to an array
  for (let i = 0; i <= pages; i += 1) {
    console.log('i=', i);
    options = {
      headers: {
        'Private-Token': token,
      },
      params: {
        order_by: 'created_at',
        sort: 'desc',
        per_page: 100,
        page: i,
      },
    };
    axios.get(url, options)
      .then((result) => { console.log(result.data); })
  }
```

Comment: can you post your sub arrays (page array/list) structure

Comment: It's Gitlab's API I am working with - and they have good docs and sample responses

The deployments api
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/deployments.html#list-project-deployments

Their pagination https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#pagination

Comment: And I am struggling to formulate the goal succinctly I know :)   But basically its a summary of deployment stats over a year. For which their can be 3000-4000 results per year so thats why I think its important to fiter the dataset before throwing it into the state

Comment: When you're doing all requests async, you'll loose the Sorting, and you won't really know when all requests are done. You could use `Promise.all()` when all of request promises have resolved. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array for the total results:

```
const results = [];
```

Where you're logging, parse each individual result:

```
result.data.forEach(item => {
  results.push({
     id: item.id,
     ref: item.ref,
     environment: item.environment.name,
     status: item.status,
     tag: item.deployable.tag
  });
});
```

Note that it may be a performance optimization to use a normal `for` loop instead of `forEach`.

Comment: thanks! This seems to work nicely and is something I tried before it one of my MANY iterations. I must have been doing something stupid and discarded it for another method because now I retried it with your code as a template and it seems to work nicely!
I am curious about the performance between for and foreach you talk about - but this is happening pretty damn quick right now!

Comment: Great, no problem.  Google forEach vs for loop, there should be some results. 
 [Here is a performance test](https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS) from two years ago but on unknown browser.  For larger data sets it seems not to matter much, or even `forEach` can be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use Promise to keep the Order of requests, hence the Sorting in across pages data. The key is to put each axios call into an array, and then call `Promise.all([])` with that array to get all reponses all at once in the original order you made the requests.

```
// Use headers to get the number of pages
const pages = await axios.head(url, options)
.then((response) => response.headers['x-total-pages']);
console.log('pages=', pages); // DEBUG

let promises = [];

// Loop through and push them to an array
for (let i = 0; i <= pages; i += 1) {
  console.log('i=', i);
  options = {
    headers: {
      'Private-Token': token,
    },
    params: {
      order_by: 'created_at',
      sort: 'desc',
      per_page: 100,
      page: i,
    },
  };

  let promise = axios.get(url, options);
  // this below keep responses order
  promises.push(promise);
}

// This wait for all Axios calls to be resolved as promise
Promise.all(promises)
  .then((result) => {
    // now if you have 10 pages, you'll have result[0] to result[9], each of them is an axios response
    console.log(result[0].data);
    console.log(result[1].data); // if pages > 0

    let items = []; // you can declare it outside too for Scope access
    for (let i = 0; i <= pages; i += 1) {
      // so many records, then take the minimum info
      if (result[i].data.length >= 1000) {
        result[i].data.forEach(item => {
          items.push({
            id: item.id,
            ref: item.ref,
            environment: item.environment.name,
            status: item.status,
            tag: item.deployable.tag
          });
        }
      } else {
        // Not so many records then take all info
        items = items.concat(result[i]);
      }
    }

    // TODO: do whatever you want with the items array now

  });
```

Comment: This is not something I am using in the working solution right now, but I wanted to take the time to say thanks! Its a nice intro to a couple of things I was thinking about for when I get past the MVP :)

Comment: That's kind. U're welcome. Because an axios request already returns a promise, it's easy to tied them together if you want them all at once. Good work with your stuffs

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here to map the original objects into simplified ones with only a subset of the properties:

```js
const newResult = result.data.map(d => ({
                                   id: d.id,
                                   ref: d.ref,
                                   environmentName: d.environment.name,
                                   status: d.deployable.status,
                                   deployableTag: d.deployable.tag
                                 }))
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    "created_at": "2016-08-11T07:36:40.222Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-11T07:38:12.414Z",
    "deployable": {
      "commit": {
        "author_email": "admin@example.com",
        "author_name": "Administrator",
        "created_at": "2016-08-11T09:36:01.000+02:00",
        "id": "99d03678b90d914dbb1b109132516d71a4a03ea8",
        "message": "Merge branch 'new-title' into 'master'\r\n\r\nUpdate README\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSee merge request !1",
        "short_id": "99d03678",
        "title": "Merge branch 'new-title' into 'master'\r"
      },
      "coverage": null,
      "created_at": "2016-08-11T07:36:27.357Z",
      "finished_at": "2016-08-11T07:36:39.851Z",
      "id": 657,
      "name": "deploy",
      "ref": "master",
      "runner": null,
      "stage": "deploy",
      "started_at": null,
      "status": "success",
      "tag": false,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Administrator",
        "username": "root",
        "state": "active",
        "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80&d=identicon",
        "web_url": "http://gitlab.dev/root",
        "created_at": "2015-12-21T13:14:24.077Z",
        "bio": null,
        "location": null,
        "public_email": "",
        "skype": "",
        "linkedin": "",
        "twitter": "",
        "website_url": "",
        "organization": ""
      },
      "pipeline": {
        "created_at": "2016-08-11T02:12:10.222Z",
        "id": 36,
        "ref": "master",
        "sha": "99d03678b90d914dbb1b109132516d71a4a03ea8",
        "status": "success",
        "updated_at": "2016-08-11T02:12:10.222Z",
        "web_url": "http://gitlab.dev/root/project/pipelines/12"
      }
    },
    "environment": {
      "external_url": "https://about.gitlab.com",
      "id": 9,
      "name": "production"
    },
    "id": 41,
    "iid": 1,
    "ref": "master",
    "sha": "99d03678b90d914dbb1b109132516d71a4a03ea8",
    "user": {
      "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80&d=identicon",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Administrator",
      "state": "active",
      "username": "root",
      "web_url": "http://localhost:3000/root"
    }
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2016-08-11T11:32:35.444Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-11T11:34:01.123Z",
    "deployable": {
      "commit": {
        "author_email": "admin@example.com",
        "author_name": "Administrator",
        "created_at": "2016-08-11T13:28:26.000+02:00",
        "id": "a91957a858320c0e17f3a0eca7cfacbff50ea29a",
        "message": "Merge branch 'rename-readme' into 'master'\r\n\r\nRename README\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSee merge request !2",
        "short_id": "a91957a8",
        "title": "Merge branch 'rename-readme' into 'master'\r"
      },
      "coverage": null,
      "created_at": "2016-08-11T11:32:24.456Z",
      "finished_at": "2016-08-11T11:32:35.145Z",
      "id": 664,
      "name": "deploy",
      "ref": "master",
      "runner": null,
      "stage": "deploy",
      "started_at": null,
      "status": "success",
      "tag": false,
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Administrator",
        "username": "root",
        "state": "active",
        "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80&d=identicon",
        "web_url": "http://gitlab.dev/root",
        "created_at": "2015-12-21T13:14:24.077Z",
        "bio": null,
        "location": null,
        "public_email": "",
        "skype": "",
        "linkedin": "",
        "twitter": "",
        "website_url": "",
        "organization": ""
      },
      "pipeline": {
        "created_at": "2016-08-11T07:43:52.143Z",
        "id": 37,
        "ref": "master",
        "sha": "a91957a858320c0e17f3a0eca7cfacbff50ea29a",
        "status": "success",
        "updated_at": "2016-08-11T07:43:52.143Z",
        "web_url": "http://gitlab.dev/root/project/pipelines/13"
      }
    },
    "environment": {
      "external_url": "https://about.gitlab.com",
      "id": 9,
      "name": "production"
    },
    "id": 42,
    "iid": 2,
    "ref": "master",
    "sha": "a91957a858320c0e17f3a0eca7cfacbff50ea29a",
    "user": {
      "avatar_url": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80&d=identicon",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Administrator",
      "state": "active",
      "username": "root",
      "web_url": "http://localhost:3000/root"
    }
  }
]

const result = data.map(d => ({
  id: d.id,
  ref: d.ref,
  environmentName: d.environment.name,
  status: d.deployable.status,
  deployableTag: d.deployable.tag
}))

console.log(result)
```